# How do I modify this cron script to give date 2 days back

Tags: bash, shell, datetime, cron

In the crontab, after a script I see a parameter:
`date -d "($(date +\%Y\%m)-15) day ago" '+\%Y\%m\%d'`

This generates a date - "20190822" if ran on 23-Aug-2019 i.e. a day back.

My questions is:

1) What is the purpose of "- 15" and "$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)" here?

2) If I want to generate 2 days back, what do I do?

I have tried:
date -d "2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d'
This works on the bash screen but this doesn't run the job in the crontab.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you try a fixed day of the month with incorrect date format.
The purpose of "-15" here is to set the day to 15th day of the month, then with "day ago" you go back one day. 
Also with %Y%m you only get Year and Month, If you get 20190822 there is somewhere a date +%Y%m%d in your script.

To go back two days:

```
    date -d "-2 days" +%Y%m%d
```

I've tried this script:

```
    date_test=$(date -d "2 days ago" +%Y%m%d)
    echo $date_test > ~/test/date_test.out
```

And got 20190821 in my file.